# Composer scripts disregards Symfony console environment variable

Tags: symfony, composer-php, environment-variables, symfony-console

I am facing an issue where the build process of my Symfony application fails, as explained in many different forums (none recent). For instance:

> When doing composer install with --no-dev only the production packages
>   are installed (as it should be). However when composer launches the
>   symfony scripts they are launched in development modes and thus start
>   throwing errors when AppKernel.php can not find packages needed for
>   development. These scripts should also be executed in production mode!

[Quote source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/11704)

The above Github issue is closed, as it apparently can be fixed by setting the `SYMFONY_ENV` env variable to the environment of your choice: `export SYMFONY_ENV=prod`.

I have done that, and calling `printenv` correctly prints the variable. I can even call the Symfony console `php bin/console` manually. and it *will* launch in `prod` environment.

Success? Seemingly, but no... Calling `composer install` still forces all scripts to launch in `dev` environment. What gives?

Comment: have you tried `composer install --no-dev --env=prod`?

Comment: @LBA `--env` is not a composer option

Comment: Stupid me. Which part of the composer script is failing?

Comment: The script is not really failing, but the embedded Symfony console scripts in composer.json are launched in dev causing all sorts of havoc downstream. But those are just the outcome, not the root cause. An example is Symfony's cache clearing script; by omitting --no-dev in composer the script will execute, but it will clear the dev cache, not prod as I would have expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause appears to be the environment variable not being set globally, so whatever user the commands ended up running as, `www-data` via my deploy script, or `root`(as I called `sudo composer`?) from the console, did not have the environment variable set that I created with my default user.

Adding `SYMFONY_ENV=prod` on a new line in `/etc/environment`, and then restarting fixed the issue, and the scripts are now running in `prod`.